# php apply method on an object foreach element of an array

Tags: php

I would apply a method for each element of an array to an object, how to achieve that ?

```
$array = ['state'=>'CA','name'=>'San Francisco']
//how to call ->where on each element to produce that ?
$documents =  $this->reference
            ->where('state', '=', 'CA')
            ->where('name', '=', 'San Francisco');
            ->documents();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your code? add which framework, ORM you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $query=  $this->reference;   
    foreach($array as $field => $value) {
        $query->where($field, '=', $value);
    }
    $documents = $query->documents();
```

The foreach syntax accepts a $k => $value pattern as its second parameter; for each element in the array, you execute the code in the foreach with $k being the current key of the array, and $v being its associated value.